# Laravel API resource store a record and it's children in one submit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have an app where I am trying to store recipes. Now, a recipe will have several details, and I want to be able to save them all at the same time with the parent recipe. My models have the correct relationship declarations.

Recipe table
`id, name servings short_description`

RecipeDetail table
`id, recipe_id, qty, measurement_id, ingredient_id`

I'm using Postman to test my API. I've tried the following with no success

`{ "name": "Homemade Pizza", "recipeDetails": { "qty": 1, "measurement_id": 1, "ingredient_id": 1 },{ "qty": 1, "measurement_id": 2, "ingredient_id": 3 } }`

I expect a recipe to be entered into the DB with the name Homemade Pizza and 2 Recipe Details entered into the DB with a recipe_id = to what the newly added recipe id is. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

**Edit**

So I've done what Karl has suggested below, with the Postman structure

```
{
    "name": "Zooble Sausage-Pepper Pizza Bites",
    "servings": "2",
    "short_description": "A great dish made in a muffin tin",
    "recipe_details": [
        {
            "qty": 1,
            "measurement_id": 1,
            "ingredient_id": 1
        },
        {
            "qty": 1.5,
            "measurement_id": 2,
            "ingredient_id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Recipe model

```
public function recipeDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RecipeDetail::class);
}
```

RecipeDetail model

```
public function recipe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Recipe::class);
}
```

In my RecipeController, I have the following,

```
public function store(StoreRecipeRequest $request)
{
    $recipe = $request->user()->recipes()->create($request->validated());
    $recipe_detail_data = $request->input('recipe_details');

    $recipe->recipeDetails()->createMany($recipe_detail_data);

    return RecipeResource::collection(Recipe::with('recipeDetails')->where('id', $recipe->id)->get());
}
```

The $recipe = $request->user()->recipes()->create($request->validated()); statement works, it is adding the recipe to the db, however when it gets to adding the recipeDetail I'm getting a sql error saying that measurement_id doesn't have a default value. I'm also wondering about validation of the recipeDetails, is that handled in the first validation or does there need to be a separate validation for the details?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Recipe model, ensure you have the recipeDetails relationship defined properly.

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function recipeDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RecipeDetail::class);
    }
}
```

RecipeDetails model...

```
class RecipeDetails extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function recipe()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Recipe::class);
    }
}
```

Now, in Postman, you need to change your structure slightly.

```
{
    "name": "Homemade Pizza",
    "recipe_details": [
        {
            "qty": 1,
            "measurement_id": 1,
            "ingredient_id": 1
        },
        {
            "qty": 1,
            "measurement_id": 2,
            "ingredient_id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

In your controller, you need to do something to the effect of...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $recipeData = $request->only('name');
    $recipe = Recipe::create($recipeData);

    $recipeDetailsData = $request->input('recipe_details');
    $recipe->recipeDetails()->createMany($recipeDetailsData);

    return response()->json($recipe, 201);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I feel as though I'm almost there. I did edit my question above and asked more questions based on the results I received making the changes you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

it's not inserting `measurement_id` in recipe_details table, that's why you have that error. Check that measurement_id is in `$fillables` array in RecipeDetails model.
For validation, `$request->input` does not check for your custom FormRequest, so its not validated, try having variable like `$data = $request->validated();`
and then use `$data` variable like:

```
$recipeDetailData = $data['recipe_details'];
```

Comment: For validation, doing it the way you suggested I'm getting undefined array key "recipe_details". Will the $request->validated() in the $request->user()->recipes()->create($request->validated()); not validate all data? Then I could use $request->input('recipe_details'); Everything is working now if I do it this way.

Comment: $request->validated(); function returns only those array keys, which are defined in your form request class. do you have 'recipe_details' described there? Also, adding measurement_id in $fillables array fixed problem, right?